# Do Bible verses such as (1 Corinthians 6:9, 10; compare Leviticus 20:13.) condemn homosexuality, or do these verse refer to pedophilia?

Tags: homosexuality

Do Bible verses such as  (1 Corinthians 6:9, 10; compare Leviticus 20:13.) condemn homosexuality, or do these verses refer to pedophilia? There seems to be some controversy over the exact meaning. Is the Hebrew context clear or ambiguous concerning the meaning?

Comment: Hello John! There is a related question, which adresses well just these two passages. The word in 1. Cor. 6 is "arseno-koites", which means "male-bed", which implicates just that kind of homosexual activity that is implied in Leviticus. Apparently the Septuagint uses these "arsen" and "koite" words in explaining the commandment. https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/15490/44115

Comment: Have you ever asked yourself why Christianity would condemn pedophilia in the first place ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate . . . . . Does this answer your question? [What did Paul mean by "Arsenokoitēs"? Was he condemning homosexual activity as we know it today?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/what-did-paul-mean-by-arsenokoit%c4%93s-was-he-condemning-homosexual-activity-as-w)

Answer (score 7):

These two verse (Lev 20:13 and 1 Cor 6:9, 10) are extremely controversial in some quarters of Christianity, especially some churches whose raison d'etre is congregations of gay, homosexual and lesbian adherents.  So let us proceed methodically and clinically.

**Words μαλακός, ἀρσενοκοίτης**

The operative words in 1 Cor 6:9 with their respective meanings are as follows:

**μαλακοὶ** (malakoi) is the plural of μαλακός (malakos) which, according to BDB means:

> **pertaining to being passive in a same-sex relationship, *effeminate***, especially of catamites, or men and boys who are sodomized by other males in such a relationship

**ἀρσενοκοῖται** (arsenokoitai) is the plural of ἀρσενοκοίτης (arsenokoites) which, according to BDAG means:

> **a male who engages in sexual activity with a person of his own sex, *pederast***

Note that this word, ἀρσενοκοίτης (arsenokoites) is a compound word which literally means man-bed, ie, is a direct reference to sexual activity between men.

It appears that Paul uses this unique word to directly refer to Lev 20:13 in the LXX because it reads:

> καὶ ὃς ἂν κοιμηθῇ μετὰ **ἄρσενος κοίτην** γυναικός, βδέλυγμα ἐποίησαν
> ἀμφότεροι· θανατούσθωσαν, ἔνοχοί εἰσιν = And whoever shall lie with a male as with a woman, they have both wrought abomination; let them die the death, they are guilty.

This well-reflects the underlying Hebrew making the intent quite clear - a condemnation of homosexual activity.

Comment: Good answer. +1  While the question did not directly address sodomy/Sodom, many people link that to the issue on account of Genesis 19.  While homosexuality was certainly a part of that story, their sin is also connected with _hedonism_ in general.