# Does the Bible condemn homosexuality?

Tags: sin, homosexuality

Biblical references on homosexuality.

Comment: Welcome to BH. The following question on this site has received many up-votes: "What did Paul mean by 'Arsenokoites'? Was he condmning homosexual activity as we know it today?" I think the answers it received probably cover every aspect of your inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It condemns homosexual acts, but the question of the Bible's attitude toward homosexuality per se is controversial.

Leviticus 20:13

> If a man lies with a male as with a woman, both of them have committed
> an abomination; they shall be put to death, their blood is upon them.

The Hebrew Bible (OT) does not deal with homosexuality in the sense of sexual preferences if they are not acted upon. For a discussion of NT attitudes see [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8493/what-did-paul-mean-by-arsenokoit%c4%93s-was-he-condemning-homosexual-activity-as-w) or related topics that come up in the search engine at the top of the page.

Comment: I appreciate you implied distinction between "homosexual acts" and homosexual orientation. +1.  One also has numerous NT references such as: Rom 1:26, 27, 1 Cor 6:9, 1 Tim 1:8-11, Jude 7.